Configuring Replicator to handle failover scenarios in camel
In order to configure an additional interceptor for consumers from initial deployment in the source cluster an interceptor must be configured to allow consumers to resume when reading topics that are replicated to the secondary cluster.
Confluent support (we use Confluent provider for Kafka) suggest us to:

configure the property

interceptor.classes=io.confluent.connect.replicator.offsets.ConsumerTimestampsInterceptor


add this dependency in the maven project:

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
    <artifactId>timestamp-interceptor</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.1</version>
</dependency>

Ok for the dependency, but how can configure the property in camel?
Best regards.
